# What is wrong with my while statement? Else statement won't write

Tags: c#, while-loop

Everything runs correctly except the else statement. It gets skipped over once the numbers are equal to each other. It doesn't say "You got it" at the end.

```
//declare variables
int number = 4;
int guessCount = 0;
int guess;

//get first number
Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10:");
guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
guessCount = guessCount + 1; //increment counter

while (guess != number) //keep repeating until number is chosen
{
    guessCount = guessCount + 1; //increment counter

    if (guess < number) //if statement if guess is less than number
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low.");
    }
    else if (guess > number) //if statement if guess is more than number
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high.");
    }
    else //
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You got it!!");
    }

    //end of while to ask for a new guess
    Console.WriteLine("Guess again: ");
    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

//display output
Console.WriteLine("You figured it out in " + guessCount + " guesses.");
Console.ReadLine(); //keep window open
```

Comment: `while (guess != number)`

Comment: I can't wait to win and get the answer "You got it! Guess again"

Comment: you need to guess twice in a row in order to exit the `while` loop

Answer (score 2):

When it is coming into the `while` loop, it means that `guess` is `!=` `number` and the only state that is possible here is `guess < number` and `guess > number` that you have already checked for, and `guess = number` is meaningless because if the `guess` is equal to `number` it doesn't even comes into the `while` loop. This is why your `else` statement never executes because the only state that your `else` statement is checking for is `guess == number`.

Answer (score 2):

Your **while** expression states: **guess** **!= number** which is true as long as the user does not type in **4** (your hardcoded value). You are setting **guess** right before the **while** expression gets checked, so if the user types in the right number, the while expression will be false and it will be jumped over. I commented your code at the problems' locations.

```
//declare variables
int number = 4;
int guessCount = 0;
int guess;

//get first number
Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10:");

// Problem A: user types in 4 -> guess becomes equal to number -> while expression gets false -> while body will not be executed
guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (guess != number) //keep repeating until number is chosen
{
    guessCount = guessCount + 1; //increment counter
    if (guess < number) //if statement if guess is less than number
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low.");
    }
    else if (guess > number) //if statement if guess is more than number
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high.");
    }
    else //
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You got it!!");
    }

    //end of while to ask for a new guess
    Console.WriteLine("Guess again: ");

    // Problem B: user types in 4 -> guess becomes equal to number -> while expression gets false -> loop ends
    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   
}
```